# Parsing a CSV with a column containing JSON Data using CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

What I am attempting to do is parse a CSV file that contains a column of JSON data. For this example, let's say the CSV looks like this:

```
id1,4000,"{"red":"#f00","green":"#0f0","blue":"#00f"}",color_pattern1
id2,300,"{"magenta":"#f0f","yellow":"#ff0","black":"#000"}",color_pattern2
```

Perhaps relevant to this is that the CSV file exists in an Azure Storage Account as a blob and not locally, but that hasn't presented any issues.

I am attempting to use the package [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) for this exercise. However, although I can load the CSV I am running into an issue where the commas from the JSON data within the CSV are being treated as delimiters. Unfortunately, I will have to use a comma delimited file as opposed to a different delimiter.

Thus far I have tried the following:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = false,
    BadDataFound = null
};

TextReader tr = new StreamReader(blobContent);
using (var csv = new CsvReader(tr, config))
{
    
    var record = new CSVData();
    var records = csv.EnumerateRecords(record);
    foreach (var r in records)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"JSON Data: {r.JsonData}");
        Console.WriteLine($" Colour Pattern ID: {r.ColourPatternId}");
    }

}
```

```
public class CSVData
{
    [Index(0)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public string Intensity { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public string JsonData { get; set; }
    [Index(3)]
    public string ColourPatternId { get; set; }
}
```

This works insofar as not producing any errors, with the `config` of `BadDataFound = Null` but I am not sure how to have it treat the JSON data properly.

Comment: Can you change the CSV data? Reason: The CSV is invalid. You must escape the delimiter in values, to this is INVALID `1,"{"b": "c"}",2`. This would be VALID `1,"{""b"": ""c""}",2`.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen -- oh, good catch. I didn't realize the data was being generated improperly. This should work, thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

@ChristophLütjen's comment is the ideal solution.  If you can, change the output to properly escape the double quotes in the JSON data.

Convert `,"{"red":"#f00"..."blue":"#00f"}",` to `,"{""red"":""#f00""...""blue"":""#00f""}",`

If, however, you can't change the output and you know the JSON data will always have the same structure of 3 colors, you could use a more manual approach to read the data.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var data = new StringBuilder();
    data.AppendLine("id1,4000,\"{\"red\":\"#f00\",\"green\":\"#0f0\",\"blue\":\"#00f\"}\",color_pattern1");
    data.AppendLine("id2,300,\"{\"magenta\":\"#f0f\",\"yellow\":\"#ff0\",\"black\":\"#000\"}\",color_pattern2");

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
        Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape
    };

    TextReader tr = new StringReader(data.ToString());
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(tr, config))
    {
        var records = new List<CSVData>();
        
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            records.Add(new CSVData
            {
                Id = csv.GetField(0),
                Intensity = csv.GetField(1),
                JsonData = csv.GetField(2).TrimStart('"') + "," + csv.GetField(3) + "," + csv.GetField(4).TrimEnd('"'),
                ColourPatternId = csv.GetField(5)
            });
        }
        
        records.Dump();
        
    }
}

public class CSVData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Intensity { get; set; }
    public string JsonData { get; set; }
    public string ColourPatternId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, that is the ideal solution and I should be able to change the output. My actual CSV is far larger and so is the JSON column within it, but your suggestion should work all the same. Much appreciated for this.